# How do I evaluate an attribute of an SVG conditionally?

Tags: xslt, svg

I want to evaluate if the `font-size` attribute is less than "34". How can I do this in XSLT?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 17.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
     <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
     <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="1024px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 1024 100" enable-background="new 0 0 1024 100" xml:space="preserve">

     <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 11.9 60.2537)" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'OpenSans'" font-size="35">Text</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Some context would be useful here. The obvious answer: `@font-size &lt; 34` will probably be meaningless without it.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't much context here to go on, but this should help:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*[@font-size &lt; 34]">
    <xsl:comment>
        <xsl:text>What is this?</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>A font for ants?</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>How can we be expected to teach children to learn how to read...</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>if they can't even see the font?</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>I don't wanna hear your excuses!</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>The building has to be at least... three times bigger than this!</xsl:text>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:comment>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to this SVG file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 17.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="1024px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 1024 100" enable-background="new 0 0 1024 100" xml:space="preserve">

     <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 11.9 60.2537)" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'OpenSans'" font-size="35">Bigger Text</text>
     <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 11.9 60.2537)" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'OpenSans'" font-size="20">Smaller Text</text>
</svg>
```

Gives this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 17.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  --><svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" width="1024px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 1024 100" enable-background="new 0 0 1024 100" xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

     <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 11.9 60.2537)" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'OpenSans'" font-size="35">Bigger Text</text>
     <!--What is this?A font for ants?How can we be expected to teach children to learn how to read...if they can't even see the font?I don't wanna hear your excuses!The building has to be at least...three times bigger than this!-->
</svg>
```